# At what resolution will an iPhone only app run at on an iPad Pro?

Tags: ipad

If I run an iPhone only app on an iPad or iPad mini the app simulates running on a 3.5" screen. If I run the same app iPhone only on an iPad Pro what will iPhone device/screen size will it simulate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 375x667pts or 4.7" (iPhone 6 screen)

When running and iPhone only app in the iPad Pro simulator in Xcode 7.1 (publicly available in the App Store) the screen point resolution is reported as 375x667 or a 4.7" screen. This also equates to an iPhone 6 or an iPhone 6+ in display zoom mode. See PaintCode's guide for more details on display zoom mode.

- http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions